# Twilio PHP / API - Searching for All SMS Messages With a Phone Number

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I use the following to get a list of recent messages - both incoming and outgoing - from Twilio:

```
$twilio = new Services_Twilio(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
$twilio->account->messages->getPage(0, 300);
```

I can search for all incoming messages from a particular number with:

```
$twilio->account->messages->getPage(0, 300, array(
    'from' => 19994442222
));
```

And vice versa by changing the `from` key to `to`.

How do I search for all incoming and outgoing messages related to a particular number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You'll have to make separate requests to get the messages to your number and from your number as you described, there's no way in the API to get messages that are to *or* from a number.

Alternatively, you could set up the number on its own under a [subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) and just requests all messages from that subaccount, thus retrieving only messages to and from that number.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I just built some internal APIs based on this logic and then noticed when I passed in a `from` key value to `getPage()`, I would get not only all the messages from that particular phone number, but all messages sent to that number too.  This simplifies what I have to do on my end, but seems a little counter intuitive.  Can you confirm that passing in a `from` key value is indeed supposed to return all to / from messages, or is this an unintended bug?

Comment: Hey Lloyd, that doesn't sound right to me. Could you send some details to help@twilio.com and they will be able to look into it. Thanks.